# Python 3: Lists and loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

I need help with my code when answering the following question.

An arithmetic progression is a sequence of numbers in which the distance (or difference) between any two successive numbers is the same. This in the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, ..., the distance is 2 while in the sequence 6, 12, 18, 24, ..., the distance is 6.

Given the positive integer distance and the non-negative integer n, create a list consisting of the arithmetic progression between (and including) 1 and n with a distance of distance. For example, if distance is 2 and n is 8, the list would be [1, 3, 5, 7].

Associate the list with the variable  arith_prog.

I updated my progress:

```
arith_prog = []
for i in range(1, n, distance):
    arith_prog.append(n)
    total = n + distance
```

While the suggestions made so far were helpful, I still haven't arrived at the correct solution turingscraft codelab is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm responding to this as a homework question, since you seem to be indicating that's what it is:

> First of all, you never initialize `n`. What starting value should it
>   have?
>
> Second, you don't need two loops here - all you need is one.
>
> Third, why are you passing `distance` to `range()`? If you pass two
>   arguments to `range()` they're treated as a lower and upper bound,
>   respectively - and `distance` is probably not a bound.

Comment: n is already initialized (the online software), I understand what you're saying though.  Distance should be the step part of range(start, stop, step).

Comment: If you're using the `step` argument for `range()`, you no longer need a loop.

Comment: @Purply.Platypus As Jon Clements also noted, the generator which `range()` produces can be passed to `list()` to create a list - and if you're already using the step argument for range, it produces exactly the list you want, which means you don't need to do anything to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The range function takes up to three arguments; start, stop and step. You want

```
list(range(1, n, distance))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you have `arith_prog.append(n)`. You need to replace the `.append(n)`  with an `.append(i)` because we are adding the value in that range to list. I just did this homework for 15 minutes ago and that was one of the correct solutions. I made the same error you did.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
arith_prog = []
n = 5 #this is just for example, you can use anything you like or do an input
distance = 2 #this is also for example, change it to what ever you like
for i in range(1,n,distance):
    arith_prog.append(i)
print(arith_prog) #for example this prints out [1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this exercise on myprogramminglab. You were very close. Try this:

```
arith_prog = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1, distance):
        arith_prog.append(i)
        total = n + distance
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Working through MPL and came across this problem, accepted answer below:

```
arith_prog=[]

for i in range(1,n+1,distance):
    arith_prog.append(i)
```